# Microsoft Dynamics GP database Insert method

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps, azure-logic-apps, dynamics-gp

Can you please let me know the adapter/connector for inserting the data in to Dynamics GP database from Azure Logic Apps?

Comment: Did you google "Azure logic app adapters?" First hit: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-connectors-list/.

Comment: Hi David, I have already verified those URLs. seems I couldn't able to find out any built in connector for Dynamics GP. thats why I am just wondering is there any other way to integrate logic apps with Dynamics GP.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Dynamics GP isn't yet supported out of the box.  The only option for now would be to extend with a custom connector to interface with GP for now.  Would be a great connector to vote for here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps

Comment: Thanks Jeff. So we need to create a Custom API APP to integrate dynamics GP in on-premise. could you please provide any samples for creating custom API APP?

Comment: Definitely - we have a lot in our github [here](https://github.com/logicappsio) and some details on how to build them [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-create-api-app/).  I actually just finished writing a blog post [here](http://hollan.io) on building a node.js connector (usually I prefer .NET but any API App will work).

Once built - you will likely want to leverage an on-premises solution like Azure Hybrid Connections or Azure VNet to gain access to your on-premises instances.